# systemd is hanging when I start or restart a service

Tags: systemd

I'm new to systemd after upgrading to 16.04 and I'm encountering a problem with starting and restarting services. When I run (for example)...

```
systemctl start djalbat.com
```

...it seems to work, however I don't get the prompt back, it just appears to hang. If I `ctrl-c` to get the prompt back and then test whether the service has started, it appears to have done so. I wonder what there is in the configuration that would cause this to happen? Here it is:

```
[Unit]
Description=djalbat.com


[Service]
Type=forking
WorkingDirectory=/var/www/djalbat.com/
ExecStart=/usr/bin/node ./bin/main.js start 2>&1 >> /var/log/djalbat.com.log


[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Also, if someone could point out the need for the last `WantedBy` directive, that would be appreciated.

Comment: It might be because the service is configured to fork but actually it does not fork. What happens when you execute the command from `ExecStart` in a terminal? Does it put itself into the background? If not, use `Type=simple`.

Comment: Let me try that. I put in that directive, much like the `WantedBy` directive, simply because I'd seen it so many times in sample configurations.

Comment: That worked, many thanks! If you have a moment, please make your comment into an answer. Then I can accept it, which might help others coming here. Thanks again!

Comment: Not your question and besides the point but you should not redirect to file and let the journal system handle it.  What you have there could run you into storage issues

Comment: I have a similarly hanging unit, but it is `Type=oneshot`. Should I change this to simple too? Not sure why it would cause it to hang...

Answer (score 35, accepted):

So it turned out that the command that is executed with the `ExecStart` configuration did not *fork* whereas the `systemd` service was configured for a forking executable. This lead `systemctl` to wait for the for of the executable leading to a not returning command line.

The correct configuration for an executable that does not *fork* is to use `Type=simple`.

```
[Unit]
Description=djalbat.com

[Service]
Type=simple
WorkingDirectory=/var/www/djalbat.com/
ExecStart=/usr/bin/node ./bin/main.js start 2>&1 >> /var/log/djalbat.com.log

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

The `WantedBy` is needed to connect this unit with a target, so this unit or service is started automatically when the appropriate target is reached  and the service is enabled to start automatically with

```
systemctl enable djalbat
```

Don't forget to refresh `systemd` after you have made changes to your service files with

```
systemctl daemon-reload
```

Comment: Then what does type=notify mean?

Comment: @djangofan `type=notify` is for services that make use of sd_notify API to notify systemd about various state changes *(e.g. whether it is ready, or is waiting for something, etc.)*.